# Make Orchard CMS completely private

Tags: orchardcms, private

I'd like to make a Orchard CMS website private and visible only to registered users.

Is this process similar to any other MVC 3 website by just editing the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this hasn't been a scenario we've been aiming for specifically. You can of course make it work like any MVC 3 app, yes, but we're also adding the capability to configure it this way from the admin UI in the upcoming version 1.5.

Comment: Thank you! So before I install, I should add a web.config section and it allow any unauthenticated user to redirect to the login page?

Comment: Was there ever a way added to accomplish this?

Comment: Of course, yes: just remove the viewing permission from the anonymous role.